# LibGDX - change actor's texture

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Is there a way to change actor texture without creating a new object?

I want to change my `ImageButton` texture when `resize()` is called, and for example for `screen > 800px`, `ImageButton` have bigger texture, and if `screen <= 800px`, `ImageButton` have smaller texture?

Now when I'm increasing my window size, `ImageButton` is scaling up but quality is bad so I want to load bigger texture.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change it in `ImageButton`'s style and convert your `Texture` to `Drawable` using `TextureRegionDrawable`:

```
// load your texture:
Texture newImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("biggerImage.png"));

// get button's style
ImageButtonStyle style = myButton.getStyle();
Drawable drawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(newImage));
style.imageUp = drawable;
style.imageDown = drawable;
```

Done!

@Edit

`new TextureRegionDrawable` won't allocate memory, because we pass an existing 'newImage' texture to it's constructor, BUT - it's a bad programming practice to make objects in places like `render()`, `resize()` etc. To do this right, declare two `Textures` at the start of your screen, big and small one, declare two `Drawables`, also at the start and load them via new `TextureRegionDrawable` and then in `resize()` put only:

```
if(screenSizeIsBig){ // your condition for big screen size
    style.imageUp = bigDrawable;
    style.imageDown = bigDrawable;
}else{ // 
    style.imageUp = smallDrawable;
    style.imageDown = smallDrawable;
}
```

Comment: so I need to use it all time when `resize()` is called? is there no problem with calling new `TextureRegionDrawable` all time when screen is resized?

Comment: I've edited the answer :)

Comment: Thank you :) last question, if it's bad programming practice to make objects in `resize()`, maybe better idea will be make object in `AssetLoader` class, when game reloading textures? I will support 5 different resolution and I'm affraid that my textures will allocate to much memory when I load 5 different `Texture` and `Drawable` for each `ImageButton` in one time

Comment: Are you creating your game only for mobiles?

Comment: Yes, for android only

Comment: If you target all 5 aspect ratios, I would create the asset manager, create 5 sets of different graphics and in the beginning of your app call a different method for each resolution for example: load16_9Assets(), load5_3Assets() etc. Your screen won't resize cause you can't resize the app on Android/iOS ;)

Comment: Hmm, ok :) thank You, I'm testing my game on dekstop all time and I have a lot of "resized" logs :)

Comment: On Desktop you can resize your app (you can disable it in Launcher class). Type in google 'libgdx disable resize'. By the way, even if you disable it, on Desktop, Android and iOS resize will still be called few times (at least on application start as I remember), so keep in mind and remember this! :)